# Tiling in Matrix multiplication with OpenMP task

Tags: c, openmp, matrix-multiplication, tiling

I have following working code for matrix multiplication (with tiling) which is producing results correctly:

```
void ProcessTile(int d1stride, int d2stride, int d3stride) {

        for (int i=d1stride ; i<(d1stride+BLOCKSIZE) ; i++) //covering rows of tile
        {
            for (int j=d2stride ; j<(d2stride+BLOCKSIZE) ; j++) //covering columns of tile (or rows if transpose)
            {
                __m128 vsum = _mm_set1_ps(0.0f);
                for (int k=d3stride ; k<(d3stride+BLOCKSIZE); k+=4) //covering convolution of vectors in a tile
                {
                    __m128 vx = _mm_load_ps(&x2[i][k]);  //loads up 4 floats into a __m128
                    __m128 vy = _mm_load_ps(&y2[j][k]);  //loads up 4 floats into a __m128
                    vsum = _mm_add_ps(vsum, _mm_mul_ps(vx, vy));
                }
                vsum = _mm_hadd_ps(vsum, vsum);
                vsum = _mm_hadd_ps(vsum, vsum);
                vsum = _mm_add_ps(vsum, _mm_load_ss (&r2[i][j]));
                _mm_store_ss(&r2[i][j], vsum);
            }
        }
}

MatrixMultiply()
{    
#pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp single
        {
            for(i=0 ; i<N ; i+=BLOCKSIZE) //covering tiled-rows of entire matrix
            {
                for(j=0 ; j<N ; j+=BLOCKSIZE) // covering tiled-columns of entire matrix
                {
                    #pragma omp task firstprivate(i,j,k)
                    for(k=0 ; k<N ; k+=BLOCKSIZE) //covering tiled-multiplication of two matrix-vectors
                    {
                        ProcessTile(i,j,k);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

However I am looking to do tiling on fine granularity level which is not working at the moment. I'll explain the working/approach with a snapshot attached
[matrix multiplication with tiling diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYqgz.jpg)

The purpose of the above code is to generate OpenMP tasks and actual work is happening in ProcessTile(...). Snapshot has 8x8 matrix with BLOCKSIZE of 4 (i.e. 4 tiles in all matrices and each tile is 2x2 size).

The working scenario which is producing expected correct results and performance

```
C[0][0] = (A[0][0]xB[0][0]) + (A[0][1]xB[1][0]) //This is tiled multiplication i.e. A[0][0] is 2x2 matrix etc.
```

The scenario which is not working and I am looking to make work is to change innermost task generating loop from

```
#pragma omp task firstprivate(i,j,k)
for(k=0 ; k<N ; k+=BLOCKSIZE) //covering tiled-multiplication of two matrix-vectors
{
    ProcessTile(i,j,k);
}
```

to

```
for(k=0 ; k<N ; k+=BLOCKSIZE) //covering tiled-convolution of two matrix-vectors
{
   #pragma omp task firstprivate(i,j,k)
   ProcessTile(i,j,k);
}
```

Above change results in the following generation of tasks and tilled multiplication

```
C[0][0] += (A[0][0]xB[0][0]) //tiled multiplication done by 'task X'

C[0][0] += (A[0][1]xB[1][0]) //tiled multiplication done by 'task Y'
```

My answers go wrong when I made the above change. The reason I am looking to do this way to have independent memory regions for each task/thread inside each matrix.

Both tasks are doing accumulative operation so not sure why getting wrong answers. What I might be missing? Is there any way I can communicate info to the task generation code which goes along the lines of 'task Y' starts after when 'task X' finishes? I am not sure if such dependency is required for such an accumulative operation or a good way to solve the problem. Maybe there is another way.

Comment: Because now you have multiple tasks sharing the same value of `i` and `j` and you need to protect from concurrent updates to the corresponding element of `C`. That's my best guess without knowing what's exactly the code behind `ProcessTile()`.

Comment: Note that an easy way to protect your code is to use *task dependencies* on `C` memory blocks. However, this is probably not the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: I have added ProcessTile function as well. Q1) What is the best way to make task dependent:  #pragma omp task firstprivate(i,j,k) depend(in:i) depend(in:j) just above the ProcessTile. Q2: What are other options from the point of view of efficiency?

Comment: Q1) `depend(in:i) depend(in:j)` does not do what you want and will probably sentimentalize all the tasks! You should rather put an array like `depend(inout:res[i*size+j]) depend(in:a[i*size+k], b[k*size+j])` where i, j and k are block offsets. Q2) I advise you to read [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/nadavrot/5b35d44e8ba3dd718e595e40184d03f0) before trying to parallelize efficiently this code.